# PHP 5.5.9 , XSLT 1.0 pass nodes to template

Tags: php, xslt-1.0

I try get node value by node name from parameter passed to template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<test>
<test1>test1_descr</test1>
<test2>test2_descr</test2>
<test3>test3_descr</test3>
</test>
</root>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="report">
<xsl:apply-templates select="list">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="/root/test"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$node/*[local-name() = 'test1']"/> -- error_string
     <xsl:value-of select="$node"/> -- result_string
 <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
 ....
</xsl:template>
```

When I call 'error_string', I see error: **XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Invalid type.** When I call 'result_string', I see this in output:

```
test1_descr
test2_descr
test3_descr
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The error you claim cannot be reproduced using your code. There are other errors - you are missing the closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` tag and `<xsl:apply-templates select="item">` is not closed - but if you fix those, no error is produced.

Comment: If I comment my 'error_string', all working.

Answer (score -1):

The issue resolved. It was mistake in my code. The template '`list`' called from few parts and in one of part was missed '`xsl:with-param`' element.  Thanks for attention!